# InStr(1, cell.Value, "-") doesn't seem to be working with Not

Tags: vba, excel

I have a conditional that doesn't seem to work.

```
If Not InStr(1, cell.Value, "-") Then
    'Do Something
Else
    'Do something else
End If
```

Where `cell.Value` are either numbers in a spreadsheet with a dash: "6621-123", or without a dash: "555321"

The first `If` let's both through and the `Else` is ignored. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`InStr` returns `0` on no match (not -1 as VBA string indexes are 1 based) 
and `not 0` is `true` (`-1`); so are all other possible values > 0 that can be returned.

```
If InStr(1, cell.Value, "-") = 0 Then
    '// not present
Else
    '// present
```

Comment: Praise the lord. Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0):

> The first If let's both through and the Else is ignored.

I would think that if one of the samples' actual [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) contained a hyphen (aka `Chr(45`) and the other did not then the behavior would not be the same for both of your samples regardless of whether you got the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)'s syntax correct. What you have is enough to determine a True/False condition¹ although I typically use a `CBool` wrapper around the Instr to remind myself that its result is being used in a boolean fashion.

I believe that your 'value' showing a hyphen is actually `6621123` not `6621-123` and that **number formatting** has been applied to the cell (e.g. custom number format of `0000-000`. In this case, if you want to determine the existence of a hyphen in the **displayed value** use the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx).

```
If CBool(InStr(1, cell.Text, "-")) Then
    'hyphen exists as seen on worksheet either in .Value or .Text
Else
    'hyphen does not exist as seen on worksheet
End If
```

---

¹ <sub>In VBA **False** is zero and for all intents and purposes, **True** is anything that is not False. Strictly speaking, a True in VBA resolves mathematically as (-1) while a worksheet TRUE resolves as 1.</sub>